# How to append url in Apache Web server to redirect to weblogic app server

Tags: apache, web, location, weblogic

I am trying to redirect a url from APache Web server to Weblogic App server.

THe url which is coming currently to the web server is :

```
http://domainname:80/meas_reporting
```

I am using the weblogic plugin in the web server to redirect the call to weblogic app server.
I want to append NGNHReporting in the url like ,

```
http://weblogichost:61001/meas_reporting/NGNHReporting
```

For this i have added the DefaultFileName property inside the Location Tag.

PFB the Location tag which I have used :

```
<Location ~ /meas_reporting>
SetHandler weblogic-handler
WebLogicHost ipaddress
WeblogicPort 61001
DefaultFileName NGNHReporting
Debug ERR
WLLogFile /software/bea/apache/2.2.23/logs/wl_proxy_managed.log
WLTempDir /software/bea/apache/2.2.23/logs
  </Location>
```

I checked access logs of Web server, the url being passed still does not add NGNHReporting in the url.

It still passes  /meas_reporting only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

post pending of the url is not possible . Made sure to change the incoming url pattern to resolve this issue.

Pre-pending is allowed. post-pending is not possible directly in a simple way.